# Distance between Fourier distributions of independent random Boolean functions

Tags: boolean-functions, fourier-analysis

For a boolean function $f: \{-1,+1\}^n \to \{-1,+1\}$, the squared Fourier coefficients $\{\hat{f}(S)^2\}_{S \subseteq \{0,1\}^n}$ form a probability distribution. I want to know what the total variation distance between the Fourier distributions looks like for two independent random functions $f$ and $g$. In particular, I want to know what the expected value of this total variation distance is, and I want a lower bound on the probability that it is less than (say) $\frac{1}{100}$.

I know that for each $S$, $\hat{f}(S)$ follows a shifted binomial distribution with mean 0 and variance $2^{-n}$. I have attempted to use this to upper bound the expectation in the following way:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{f,g}\frac{1}{2}\sum_S\left|\hat{f}(S)^2 - \hat{g}(S)^2\right| &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_S\mathbb{E}_{f,g}\sqrt{\left(\hat{f}(S)^2 - \hat{g}(S)^2\right)^2} \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}\sum_S\sqrt{\mathbb{E}_{f,g}\left(\hat{f}(S)^2 - \hat{g}(S)^2\right)^2},
\end{align}
$$

where the last step is by Jensen's inequality.

Now each term $\mathbb{E}_{f,g}\left(\hat{f}(S)^2 - \hat{g}(S)^2\right)^2$ simplifies to $2(\mathbb{E}_f[\hat{f}(S)^4] - (\mathbb{E}_f[\hat{f}(S)^2])^2)$. $\mathbb{E}_f[\hat{f}(S)^2]$ is $2^{-n}$, and I didn't calculate $\mathbb{E}_f[\hat{f}(S)^4]$ exactly, but if you approximate the binomial distribution by a Gaussian I believe it should be $3\cdot 2^{-2n}$. Unfortunately, plugging this into the upper bound expression just gives the trivial upper bound of 1 for the total variation distance.

My intuition was that this expected value would be quite small, so I believe it should be possible to get a much better bound than this. I don't think approximating the binomial by a gaussian would have been too lossy, so probably applying Jensen's inequality here was the bad step - but I'm not sure how else to deal with the absolute difference. Any help would be appreciated.